# move a field to the left and up wherever there is a blank space in a file using shell in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I am facing  a problem while modifying a file. The file contains numeric as well as alphabetical values:
eg

```
    QWEE123

1.18E+00  1.28E+00  1.22E+00  1.78E+01  1.77E+01

1.28E+00  1.18E+00  1.28E+00  1.22E+00

6.91E-01  4.20E+00  2.80E+00  7.06E-01  1.92E+00


    REE234

3.18E+00  8.28E+00  9.22E+00  8.78E+01  3.77E+01

4.28E+00  7.18E+00  1.28E+00

5.91E-01  6.20E+00  4.80E+00  6.06E-01

4.18E+00  6.28E+00  2.22E+00  3.78E+01  7.77E+01
```

The out put I am looking for

QWEE123

```
1.18E+00  1.28E+00  1.22E+00  1.78E+01  1.77E+01  
1.28E+00  1.18E+00  1.28E+00  1.22E+00  6.91E-01
4.20E+00  2.80E+00  7.06E-01  1.92E+00


    REE234

3.18E+00  8.28E+00  9.22E+00  8.78E+01  3.77E+01    
4.28E+00  7.18E+00  1.28E+00  5.91E-01  6.20E+00
4.80E+00  6.06E-01  4.18E+00  6.28E+00  2.22E+00
3.78E+01  7.77E+01
```

The coulmns under QWEE123 and REE234 have 5 field values. I want to shift the values from the lines below to fill up the empty fields and make the rows with 5 field values. In the process the number of lines can change. I want to do it for
for the values below QWEE123, REE234 and so on ( there are 2000 more similar to QWEE and REE and there are values below these). How can i do it using shell script ?

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to achieve. Just post the desired result for the input you gave.

Comment: Are the periods part of the text file or do they indicate more similar data?

Comment: periods( ...........) indicate similar data. there are about 2000 such data paragraphs of unequal data number in say 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

This makes several assumptions about your input, but perhaps gives your what you want:

```
awk '/^[^0-9]/{printf("\n%s\n",$0); n=0} 
    /^[0-9]/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf("%s%s",$i, ++n%5 ?"  ":"\n")}}' input
```

Comment: Thanks William! that's brilliant!

Comment: it seems to work fine with cygwin. however when the number of fields is changed to 10 and number of lines to modify > 250000, then the line to which the cell(from the next line below) has to shift up remains same and the line below splits. for example:                                        4.28E+00  7.18E+00  1.28E+00
 5.91E-01  6.20E+00                                                                    4.80E+00  6.06E-01  i tried to bring up the line and append to the line above but does not work.[in Linux]